Modeling temporal dependencies in binary decision variables
This is a re-up with further information and a bit different question. I am currently building a model that tries to minimize the length of stay of patients over the planning horizon $K$. We have nurses $J$ who treat patients $I$ and supplementary medication treatment. This defines the nurse-assignment variable $a_{ijk}$ or the supplementary medication treatment $b_{ik}$. The goal of the model is to minimize the length of stay (LOS). This is my model so far:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & \sum_{i \in I} f_i \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & g_{ik} = \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} + b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{2}\\
& \sum_{i \in I} a_{ijk} \leq Max_j & \forall j \in J, k \in K \tag{3}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{4}\\
& f_i = \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} \cdot k - Entry_i + 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{5}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} a_{ij,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{6}\\
& \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{7}\\
& R_i \cdot d_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{m=1}^k a_{ijm} + E_{app} \sum_{m=1}^k b_{im} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{8}\\
& e_{ik} \leq d_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K\tag{9} \\
& e_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{10}\\
& d_{ik} \geq E_{min} \cdot b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{11}\\
& g_{ik} = 0 & \forall i \in I, k < Entry_i \tag{11}\\
& g_{i,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{12}
\end{align}
The most relevant constraint for my question is constraint (2). It ensures that if a patient is eligible for treatment he/she gets one of both options, if he/she is not, then she gets no treatment. Here $g_{ik}$ is a decision variable, where we know based on the entry date if $g_{ik}$ must be zero or 1, but since we do not know the exact duration in the hospital, we can deduct any information on this ex-ante. This leads to the problem, that $g_{ik}$ could be 1, even if the patient is discharged, leading to an assignment of either $a_{ijk}$ or $b_{ik}$. However, this should not be the case. With which constraint can I prevent this? Maybe use the binary variable $e_{ik}$, which indicates that the last day of the treatment has been reached, which is defined in constraints (7), (9), and (10). Specifically, I want to prevent such behavior f.e.
        k  2 3 4 5 6 ...

 a[i,j,k]  1 0 1 0 0 ...
 b[i,k]    0 1 0 0 0 ...
 e[i,k]    0 0 1 0 0 ...
 g[i,k]    1 1 1 0 0 ...

As discernible, on day 4, the last treatment was performed, and there all $g_{ik}$ should be zero afterwards. However my current formulation does not prevent this. Using the code below, i am able to minimize the LOS, but f.e. for some patients, i still get $G_{ik}=1$ even for $k$ values greater than $k'$ when $e_{ik'}=1$. I would appreciate any help you can give me.
This is my code:
import gurobipy as gu
from setup import *
from icecream import ic

# Model
I, K, J = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]
R_i, Entry_i, Max_j = {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, {1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 3, 5: 5}, {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1}
W, W_min, E_app, E_min = 5, 1, 0.25, 0.2

Model = gu.Model("")

d = Model.addVars(I, K, lb=0, vtype=gu.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="d")
e = Model.addVars(I, K, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="e")
f = Model.addVars(I, vtype=gu.GRB.INTEGER, name="f")
a = Model.addVars(I, J, K, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="a")
b = Model.addVars(I, K, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="b")
c = Model.addVars(I, J, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="c")
g = Model.addVars(I, K, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="g")

Model.setObjective(gu.quicksum(f[i] for i in I), gu.GRB.MINIMIZE)

for j in J:
    for k in K:
        Model.addLConstr(gu.quicksum(a[i, j, k] for i in I) <= Max_j[j])

for i in I:
    Model.addLConstr(1 == gu.quicksum(c[i, j] for j in J))
    Model.addLConstr(f[i] == gu.quicksum(e[i, k] * k for k in K) - Entry_i[i] + 1)
    Model.addLConstr(1 == gu.quicksum(a[i, j, Entry_i[i]] for j in J))
    Model.addLConstr(1 == gu.quicksum(e[i, k] for k in K))

    for k in K:
        Model.addLConstr(g[i, k] == gu.quicksum(a[i, j, k] for j in J) + b[i, k])
        Model.addLConstr(R_i[i] * d[i, k] <= gu.quicksum(gu.quicksum(a[i, j, m] for m in range(1, k + 1)) for j in J) +
                         gu.quicksum(b[i, m] for m in range(1, k + 1)) * E_app)
        Model.addLConstr(e[i, k] <= d[i, k])
        Model.addLConstr(e[i, k] <= gu.quicksum(a[i, j, k] for j in J))
        Model.addLConstr(d[i, k] >= E_min * b[i, k])

        if k < Entry_i[i]:
            Model.addLConstr(0 == g[i, k])
        elif k == Entry_i[i]:
            Model.addLConstr(1 == g[i, k])

Model.optimize()


Is a patient treated every day from entry until discharge, or just once? What in your algebraic model (not your code) indicates discharge of the patient?

Yes the patient is treated every day (including entry day and last day). It is constraint (9) which allows $e_{ik}$ take the value of one, once the treatment effectivness $d_{ik}$ is greater or equal to one.

@prubin Did you came up with a different constraint/idea?

Not really. Sutanu's answer is correct. You could also use $$g_{i,k}+e_{i,k'} \le 1 , \forall i,k,k'<k,$$ but I think Sutanu's answer yields a tighter relaxation (and definitely fewer constraints). Separate constraints are sparser. It's an empirical question which version solves faster.

$g_{i,k} \le 1 - \sum_{2}^{k-1} e_{i,k} \ \ \forall i, k$
Also you may not need $g_{ik}$ as a separate decision variable. You may substitute with $\sum_j a_{i,j,k}+b_{i,k} \ \ \forall i,k$
